# JAAS web-security on jboss 5

Tags: security, jsf, jboss, jaas

hello i'm trying to perform a  based form authentication on jboss:
these are my configuration files.
login-config.xml:

```
<application-policy name="MyPolicy">
<authentication>
    <login-module flag="required"
        code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName">java:/espritDS</module-option>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery">SELECT password FROM users WHERE
            username=?</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery">SELECT groupname FROM groups WHERE
            username=?</module-option>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
```

web.xml:

```
<!-- Security  -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secret</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/secret/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

and jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
<!-- A security domain that restricts access -->
<security-domain>java:/jaas/MyPolicy</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

i thought i don't need to setup users and roles files since i have a database where i inserted some users and roles but i'm having this exception and didn't manage to deal with it:
11:57:26,587 ERROR [UsersRolesLoginModule] Failed to load users/passwords/role files
java.io.IOException: No properties file: users.properties or defaults: defaultUsers.properties found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in your `rolesQuery`. It should looks just like that:

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery">SELECT groupname, 'Roles' FROM groups WHERE
        username=?</module-option>
```

I don't see other errors.

You can read more about DatabaseServerLoginModule modules  here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabaseServerLoginModule

Comment: Stelmach thanx, that was one error and i also forgot to restart jboss.
now the exception is gone. But i don't get redirected to the login page when i request the secret page. Could it be that i have other errors in SQL request?

Comment: @boskonovic You are welcome. I have no idea why it doesn't work. If you use SSL maybe check if it is configured. I think it can be best to ask another question with proper description.

Comment: Stelmach well it works fine now thanks to you. Actually, there was no other errors. I even managed to get ssl working but i don't need ssl for the whole application. Any suggestions? i guess i have to ask another qusetion as u said.